# Problem with assigning values to complex variables using real() and imag()

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I want to assign a value (here 0.0f) to a complex variable which I defined first using `std::complex<float>`. The real and imaginary part of the variable should be then assigned using `real(...)=0.0f` and `imag(...)=0.0f`. But by compiling I get the error "lvalue required as left operand of assignment". I tried g++ 7.5 and also 6.5 and I got this error from both.

```
temp = new float[ nfft ];
  tempComplex = new std::complex< float >[ nf ];
  if ( processing->getComponentNSToProc() ) {
for ( int i = 0; i < sampNum; i++ ) {
  temp[ i ] = srcData[ iSrc ].rcvData[ iRcv ].dataNS[ i ];
  qDebug() << "before: temp[" << i << "] =" << temp[ i ] << "; ....dataNS[" << i << "] =" << srcData[ iSrc ].rcvData[ iRcv ].dataNS[ i ] << ";";
}
for ( int i = sampNum; i < nfft; i++ ) {
  temp[ i ] = 0.0f;
  qDebug() << "before: temp[" << i << "] =" << temp[ i ] << ";";
}
for ( int i = 0; i < nf; i++ ) {
  real( tempComplex[ i ] ) = 0.0f;
  imag( tempComplex[ i ] ) = 0.0f;
```

Comment: please show the code instead of describing it. See [mcve]

Comment: Why do you think that it should be possible to assign these values? The methods real and imag return values not references, they are designed for reading not writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using a non-static member function of a class we need to use(call) it through an object of that class. So you can change your code to look like:

```
int main() 
{
    
  std::complex<float> *tempComplex = new std::complex< float >[ 3];
  
  for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) 
  {
      
      tempComplex[i].real(0.0f);
      
      tempComplex[i].imag(0.0f);
      std::cout<<tempComplex[i]<<std::endl;
   }
}
```

The above code now works because `tempComplex[i]` is an object and we access the non-static member function named `real` and `imag` of the class `std::complext<float>`through this(`tempComplex[i]`) object.

Also after everything(at appropriate point) don't forget to use `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

[real](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/real), and [imag](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/imag), can be invoked without arguments, then they will return the read only real part or imaginary part of the object. If you call them with one argument then they will modify the real/imaginary part.

For instance

```cpp
std::complex<float> z;
z.real(1.0f); // Sets the real part
x.imag(-2.0f); // Sets the imaginary part
```